# decrease mat icon svg font weight

Tags: angular-material2

I have created my custom mat icons using svg
but they looks bold.

If I set SVG directly in img tag - it looks thin, but in material icons - bold
I try font-weight, but no success

any ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

set SVG { path { fill: currentColor } } (globally)
not stroke
it was my mistake
I set currentColor for stroke